# How magnets create electricity in conductors?

Tags: electromagnetism, mathematical-physics, electricity, experimental-physics

what are the reasons for current appearing in a wire when wire is in a changing magnetic field?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is: Why does a current appear in a wire when exposed to a changing magnetic field but not in other objects, like a human body?  If this is your question, then here is your answer:

A changing magnetic field produces an electric field.  How this electric field affects the electrons in a given material depends on the properties of the material.  For a metal, where many for the electrons exist in a sort of "sea" of electrons bound to the metal but not to any particular atoms, the electrons are free to move around as determined by the electric field and a current is produced.  In a non-metallic material, where the electrons are bound to atoms, the electron wavefunctions and energy levels will be affected by the electric field but (barring an exceptionally strong electric field) the electrons will remain bound to the atoms.    So, no current.